# [DEPLOY DOMAIN]: Rails App with Heroku and Namecheap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, namecheap

I developped a rails app that I want to deploy with a domain name.
I use heroku and bought my domain on namecheap.

After configuration on namecheap and heroku I have the following message on my web page when I try to connect on my website: 'There's nothing yet here'

Do I need to do other stuff on heroku?
Thks for your help...
Here are my settings on heroku:

**Domain
Your app can be found at http://www.my-app.com**

**SSL:
Upgrade to paid dynos to configure Heroku SSL**

**Domain Name:

www.my-app.com**

**DNS Target:
www.my-app.com.herokudns.com**

On my console:

```
dig CNAME www.wines-house.com                                                                   [2.3.4]

<<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> CNAME www.my-app.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11242
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.my-app.com.        IN  CNAME

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.my-app.com. 1799    IN  CNAME   www.my-app.herokuapp.com.

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 29 11:21:22 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 88
```

Comment: In your DNS administration page just add a CNAME rule pointing to the url provided by heroku in the settings tab, which is usually like: `www.my-app.com.herokudns.com`. Does namecheap provide you an admin section for managing the domain?

Comment: thk you @JuanM that works perfectly: I change on namecheap the CNAM  to: www.my-app.com.herokudns.com.